# Basic Simultaneous equations ending up in circles...

Tags: systems-of-equations, finance

Trying to solve for U in the below set of equations.... For context this is in the development of the Binomial tree pricing model that Cox, Ross and Rubenstein developed.

$qu + (1-q)d = e^{rt}
\\ qu^{2} + (1-q)d^{2} = e^{(2r+v^{2})t}$

I was advised to find a quadratic in U but my under caffeinated brain just keeps ending up with some stupid looking equations. Appreciate this is super basic.

Comment: There are two equations, and $u$ is one of the unknowns to solve for. Which is the second unknown?

Comment: The other unknown is d

Comment: Then just eliminate $d$ between the two equations. The first equation gives $d$ in linear terms of $u$, then substituting into the second equation gives a quadratic in $u$ alone.

Comment: Thank you. I got finally somwhere with it. Am still struggling with solving the quadratic but will work at it later on. Am clearly too tired. Really appreciate your help. 

FWIW I ended up with 

$$U^2-0.5U = 2e^{v^{2}t}$$

Comment: That doesn't look right, recheck your steps. From the first equation $\,(1-q)d = e^{rt} - qu\,$. To simplify the calculations, multiply the second equation by $\,(1-q)\,$ then substitute the $\,\left((1-q)d\right)^2\,$ term and you should get $\,q(1-q)u^{2} + \left(e^{rt} - qu\right)^2 = (1-q)e^{(2r+v^{2})t}\,$. Bring everything to one side, expand and collect and you get a quadratic in $\,u\,$, but I don't see how $\,q\,$ and $\,e^{rt}\,$ could possibly cancel out.

Answer (score 0):

You have the following two equations

$ q u + (1 - q) d = A $

$ q u^2 + (1 - q) d^2 = B $

where $A = e^{rt} , B = e^{(2 r + v^2)t} $

The first is an equation of a straight line, and the second is an equation of an ellipse.

Let $u' = \sqrt{q} u $, and $ d' = \sqrt{1 - q} d $ then the first equation becomes

$\sqrt{q} u' + \sqrt{1 - q} d' = A $

and the second equation becomes

$ u'^2 + d'^2 = B $

Solve for $d'$ from the first transformed equation,

$ d' = \dfrac{ A - \sqrt{q} u' } { \sqrt{1 - q} } $

Then, plug this into the second equation

$ u'^2 + \dfrac{( A - \sqrt{q} u' )^2 }{ 1 - q } = B $

which re-arranges into

$ u'^2 - 2 u' A \sqrt{q} + A^2 - (1 - q) B = 0$

which is a quadratic equation in $u'$ and can be solved using the quadratic formula.  Once $u'$ is found, then $d'$ can be computed from the equation relating $d'$ and $u'$ above.  And finally, $u$ and $v$ can be computed from the defining equations of $u'$ and $d'$.